# Validation for duplicate input fields in Angular

Tags: angular

[image: In this image skill and exp input fields should not have the same values]

Is there a validator to check duplicate fields? like there is for matching password fields
In the demo, I am trying to give an error message, when exp and skill are the same for one div
example, 
**first name**- rak **lastname**- bhure
**skill**-java      **exp**- java
this should give an error message

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You'll need to write your own custom validator for that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read this [documentation about Validators in Angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators). To create custom validators, 1. Have your form defined and 2. create a new class; which in this case is named `AuthValidators` where it contains all your custom validators. I named the first validator to be `skillAndExpValidator`.

You may not create a custom class but rather just create the `skillAndExpValidator` function, but it is a good practice to have all your validators in one class.

**x.component.ts**

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
.......
exp: ['', [AuthValidators.skillAndExpValidator()]]
skill: ['', [AuthValidators.skillAndExpValidator()]]
.......
})
....... 
export class AuthValidators {
  static skillAndExpValidator() {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      let exp = group.get('exp').value
      let skill = group.get('exp').value

      return exp == skill ? {expEqSkillError: true} : null

   }
}
.......
```

**x.component.html**

```
.......
<span *ngIf="this.fb.get('exp').hasError('expEqSkillError')">ERROR: EXP SHOULDN'T BE EQUAL TO SKILL</span>

<span *ngIf="this.fb.get('skill').hasError('expEqSkillError')">ERROR: EXP SHOULDN'T BE EQUAL TO SKILL</span>
.......
```

Comment: when i copy pasted export class AuthValidaitions{} code block, it gave so mnay red lines in my ts file, do i need to declare it under any specific component?

Comment: I needs to be in the component you are applying the validators. Make sure to import necessary modules. . You can also put it into a separated file then just import that class into that component.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code snippet will help you:

```
 onSubmit() {
  let showError=false;
  if (this.empForm.get("employees").value) {
    this.empForm.get("employees").value.forEach(employee => {        
      if (employee) {
        console.log(employee);
        employee.skills.forEach(skill => {
          let findDuplicates = data => {
            let result = [];
            data.forEach(function(element, index) {
              if (data.indexOf(element, index + 1) > -1) {
                if (result.indexOf(element) === -1) {
                  result.push(element);
                }
              } else {
                console.log("Show error");
                showError=true;
              }
            });
            console.log(result);
          };
          const data = findDuplicates(
            employee.skills.map(skill => skill.skill)
          );
        });
      }
    });
    if(showError){
      this.empForm.setErrors({
        'duplicateSkills': true
      });
    }
    console.log(this.empForm.errors)
  }
  const firstEmployeeSkills = this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills.map(
    x => x.skill
  );
  return firstEmployeeSkills;
}
```

If there is duplicate skills, the it will setError to form.